# Clojure web app sql insert only last row when deployed to Tomcat

Tags: sql, tomcat, clojure, web-deployment

Good afternoon,

I am using Clojure 1.8, PostgreSQL 9.4 and YeSQL 0.5.2

I have an web app that has a page to insert multiple prices. I get the prices from a HTML Form using Post method. It comes as a map of vector for me. I convert it to a vector of maps so it is easier to manipulate the data. Then I delete previous entries if exists and I do the treatments to the fields and call the DB transaction to insert into the database.

When I use `lein ring server` it works fine. But when I deploy to Tomcat 9 using `lein ring uberwar`, the app inserts only the last row.

Here are the my web page:

[image: Each table row will be a SQL Insert]

Each row in the table will be a SQL Insert

My connection:

```
(ns satus-cotacao.model.connection)

(def db-spec {:classname "org.postgresql.Driver"
              :subprotocol "postgresql"
              :subname "//localhost/database"  ;; 192.168.0.x:port when using other database from the internal network.
              :user "root"
              :password "root"})
```

And my `defqueries`

```
(ns satus-cotacao.model.cotacao_model
  (:require ...
            [satus-cotacao.model.connection :refer [db-spec]]
            ...)

(defqueries "satus_cotacao/model/cotacao.sql"
            {:connection db-spec})
```

The Post request that calls the `lcto-cotacao-page` using the Form as parameter

```
POST "/cotacao/:cod" [cod & form :as session] (lcto-cotacao-page cod form session))
```

The `lcto-cotacao-page` function to call the Delete and the Insert functions.

```
(defn lcto-cotacao-page
  [cod lcto session]
  (try
    (cotacao/deleta-lcto-cotacao! cod (:identity session))
    (cotacao/insere-lctos-cotacoes! cod (:identity session) lcto)
    (layout/render "home.html" {:session session})
    (catch Exception e
      (do
        (timbre/error e)))))
```

The `delete-lcto-cotacao!` function and SQL query

```
(defn deleta-lcto-cotacao!
  [codcotacao enti_codigo]
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx db-spec]
                            (delete-lcto-cotacao! {:codcotacao codcotacao 
                                                   :enti_codigo enti_codigo} 
                                                  {:connection tx})))
-- name: delete-lcto-cotacao!
DELETE FROM lctocotacao
WHERE lcco_codentidade = :enti_codigo
AND lcco_codcontrole = :codcotacao
```

The delete works fine, it deletes all entries.

The `insere-lctos-cotacoes!` to convert from map of vector to vector of maps and create a recursive call through this vector

```
(defn insere-lctos-cotacoes!
  [cod enti lctos]
  (if (vector? (:lcco_codprod lctos))
    (let [lcto-vec (util/from-map-of-vector-to-vector-of-maps lctos)]
      (loop [lcto lcto-vec]
        (when (not-empty lcto)
          (insere-lcto-cotacao<! cod enti (first lcto))
          (recur (rest lcto)))))
    (insere-lcto-cotacao<! cod enti lctos)))
```

Then the function `insere lcto-cotacao<!` that treats the fields

```
(defn insere-lcto-cotacao<!
  [cod enti lcto]
  (let [lcto_codentidade enti
        lcto_codcontrole cod
        lcto_dtmvto (util/convert-to-data-type (.format (java.text.SimpleDateFormat. "MM/dd/yyyy") (Date.)))
        lcto_codprod (Integer. (:lcco_codprod lcto))
        lcto_qemb (bigdec (:lcco_qemb lcto))
        lcto_qtde (bigdec (:lcco_qtde lcto))
        lcto_fpgto (util/empty-field? (:lcco_fpgto lcto) false)
        lcto_preco (util/empty-field? (:lcco_preco lcto) true)
        lcto_codempresa (util/empty-field? (:lcco_codempresa lcto) false)
        new-lcto (assoc lcto :lcco_codentidade lcto_codentidade
                             :lcco_codcontrole lcto_codcontrole
                             :lcco_dtmvto lcto_dtmvto
                             :lcco_codprod lcto_codprod
                             :lcco_preco lcto_preco
                             :lcco_qemb lcto_qemb
                             :lcco_qtde lcto_qtde
                             :lcco_fpgto lcto_fpgto
                             :lcco_codempresa lcto_codempresa)]
    (insere-lcto-transaction<! (dissoc new-lcto :tpemb :descricao :codbarras :marca))))
```

And finally the `insere-lcto-transaction<!` and the SQL query

```
(defn insere-lcto-transaction<!
  [lcto]
  (jdbc/with-db-transaction [tx db-spec]
                            (insert-lcto-cotacao<! lcto {:connection tx})))

-- name: insert-lcto-cotacao<!
INSERT INTO lctocotacao (lcco_codentidade, lcco_codprod, lcco_preco, lcco_dtmvto, lcco_codempresa, lcco_fpgto, lcco_qemb, lcco_qtde, lcco_codcontrole)
VALUES(:lcco_codentidade, :lcco_codprod, :lcco_preco, :lcco_dtmvto, :lcco_codempresa, :lcco_fpgto, :lcco_qemb, :lcco_qtde, :lcco_codcontrole);
```

Well, thats it. What is strange is that it works fine when I do `lein ring server`, but when I deploy to `lein ring uberwar` it doens't work properly.

Also, I tried using Tomcat in Windows and Debian.

Does anyone have an idea why is it happening?

**EDIT**
After logging, I got some results:

When running local `lein ring server`

What the POST return into the var `form` is the same content as the key `:param` in my `session`
Also in `session`, I have the `:form-params`that has the same content, but instead of using keys like `:lcco_fpgto`, it uses strings like '"lcco_fpgto"'

```
{:lcco_fpgto ["001" "001" "001" "001"], 
:tpemb ["CX" "CX" "PT" "CX"], 
:lcco_qtde ["150.00000" "1.00000" "30.00000" "1.00000"], 
:descricao ["Cerveja 350ml Skola" "Adoc 100ml Assugrin Diet" "Cafe 500g Corol Torrado Moido" "Deterg Liq 500ml Alpes Neutro"], 
:lcco_codprod ["19" "28" "64" "123"], 
:lcco_preco ["1.00000" "2.00000" "3.00000" "4.00000"], 
:codbarras ["7896232111149" "7896060010492" "7896184000010" "7896274800124"], 
:lcco_codempresa ["001" "001" "001" "001"], 
:lcco_qemb ["12.00000" "12.00000" "10.00000" "24.00000"], 
:marca ["Skol" "Assugrin" "Corol" "Alpes"], 
:__anti-forgery-token ["Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*"]}
```

When running the deployed app:

The POST return is the same as the `:param` key inside `session` (Only the last element)

```
{:lcco_fpgto "001", 
:tpemb "CX", 
:lcco_qtde "1.00000", 
:descricao "Deterg Liq 500ml Alpes Neutro",
:lcco_codprod "123", 
:lcco_preco "4", 
:codbarras "7896274800124", 
:lcco_codempresa "001", 
:lcco_qemb "24.00000", 
:marca "Alpes", 
:__anti-forgery-token "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*"}
```

And what I found, is that the `:form-params` inside my `session` contains everything, but using strings instead of keys.

```
:form-params {
    "lcco_preco" ["1" "2" "3" "4"], 
    "tpemb" ["CX" "CX" "PT" "CX"], 
    "descricao" ["Cerveja 350ml Skola" "Adoc 100ml Assugrin Diet" "Cafe 500g Corol Torrado Moido" "Deterg Liq 500ml Alpes Neutro"],
    "lcco_codprod" ["19" "28" "64" "123"], 
    "lcco_fpgto" ["001" "001" "001" "001"], 
    "codbarras" ["7896232111149" "7896060010492" "7896184000010" "7896274800124"], 
    "marca" ["Skol" "Assugrin" "Corol" "Alpes"], 
    "lcco_qtde" ["150.00000" "1.00000" "30.00000" "1.00000"], 
    "__anti-forgery-token" ["Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*" "Unbound: #'ring.middleware.anti-forgery/*anti-forgery-token*"], 
    "lcco_qemb" ["12.00000" "12.00000" "10.00000" "24.00000"], 
    "lcco_codempresa" ["001" "001" "001" "001"]}
```

So, why is that happening? Is it wrong to use the var `form` that I get in here?

```
POST "/cotacao/:cod" [cod & form :as session] (lcto-cotacao-page cod form session))
```

Why is this difference happening?

**EDIT 2**
My middleware:

https://codeshare.io/mR7Zh

Comment: I guess you are using YeSQL. Could you please double check that your SQL files are packaged in your `war` file and are the same files that are used when you use `lein ring server`?

Comment: Sorry I forget to mention, I am using YeSQL. And the SQL file is the same. I just checked. Also, I checked PostgreSQL logs both when using `lein ring server` and when deployed. Both logs seems ok, the only diference is that when local, it shows 4 inserts, and when deployed, just 1 insert.

Comment: Please, add some logging to your code to be sure that the same HTTP requests are made and the same functions (and same number of times) are called. What about connection pool and transactions configuration?

Comment: I will try logging these request using timbre then I let you know.
I just added my `connection` and `defqueries` to the post. Do I need to configure other things?

Comment: That should be it. Please make sure to log the content of your form POST data.

Comment: I just logged both local and after deployed. The problem is: when local, the POST return a map of vectors that contains the info of the 4 rows. When deployed, it returns the map that contains only the last row. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: What your browser developer mode shows? What data is it sending?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed something when logging the session.
I got only the last element into the `:params` key, but into the `:form-params` key I have everything... And the param `form` from  here `POST "/cotacao/:cod" [cod & form :as session] (lcto-cotacao-page cod form session))` I have only the first element.

Comment: I just added my logs so you can understand better.

Comment: One more thing - please post how your middleware is configured.

Comment: Just added the link to my middleware file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110312/discussion-between-piotrek-bzdyl-and-alexis-heijmeijer).